# Why isn't jQuery scrollTo() working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use a very simple implementation of the scrollTo plugin:

http://jsfiddle.net/TPQyY/

But I can't get it to work. Any idea why it's not scrolling horizontally to reveal the next image in the list?

```
<!doctype html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $('.next').click(function(e) {
        $('ul#scrollThis').scrollTo( 'li:eq(1)', 1000, {axis:'x'} );    
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });

});
</script>

<style>

@import "http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/build/reset/reset.css";

body { padding: 100px; }

ul { list-style-type: none; width: 50px; height: 50px; overflow: hidden; }
ul li { float: left; }

</style>

<ul id="scrollThis">
    <li><img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" width="50" height="50" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.thecouchsessions.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/fat-cat.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.howstuffworks.com/gif/dog-best-friend-1.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></li>
</ul>

<a href="" class="next">Next >></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the plugin for a second, you are using an unordered list so the images are actually one after the other vertically, not horizontally.  You can see this by removing the overflow: hidden css style.

So you have a vertical list (down the Y axis) and you are locking the plugin to only scroll the x axis.  If you remove the {axis:'x'} argument you will see it scroll vertically.

If you want it to scroll horizontally then you just need to change your CSS for the UL to appear one after the other horizontally.

**UPDATE**

To achieve the horizontally aligned items (and therefore the horizontal scrolling), you need to change the UL to be wide enough to accomodate all of the items side by side (if you limit the width of the UL it will just push items down to the next line), and set *white-space* to *nowrap*.

Then set the LI's to *display:inline* (or you could use *float:left* I believe).

Now you have the items side by side, you need to crop the view so only one is displayed.  To do this wrap the UL in a container div and on this set the *width* and *height* so only one item is displayed and *overflow* to *hidden*.

Finally change your scrollto, to tell the container to scroll not the list.

This should achieve the result you are after.

```
<!doctype html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $('.next').click(function(e) {
        $('#container').scrollTo( 'li:eq(1)', 1000, {axis:'x'} );    
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });

});
</script>

<style>

@import "http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/build/reset/reset.css";

body { padding: 100px; }

ul { list-style-type: none; white-space: nowrap; width: 70000px; }
ul li { display: inline; }
#container { width:50px; height:50px; overflow:hidden;  }

</style>

<div id="container">
    <ul id="scrollThis">
        <li><img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" width="50" height="50" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.thecouchsessions.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/fat-cat.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.howstuffworks.com/gif/dog-best-friend-1.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<a href="" class="next">Next >></a>
```

Comment: Hi, yes I just realized this too. Seems to be a css issue. I am new to css and I just can't figure out how to have the list items appear next to one another and yet have the others hidden. Because if I set a fixed width to the ul and apply overflow hidden property as you mentioned this causes the lis to fall underneath one another. Do you know how I can have the lis next to one another and yet just display one using css?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the width which you have assigned to `ul`. It is sufficient enough to accomodate only one `li`. So the rest `li`'s are wrapping down even though you have set `float:left` to them.

What you need is to have a wrapper div around `ul` which should have the height and width required for a single `li` item to be shown. The width of the `ul` should be the total width of  all the `li`'s. After you do this apply `scrollTo` plugin on the wrapper div.

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TPQyY/7/)**

Comment: @Sam - Take a look at this working demo and explanation to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Main problem is that flesler is alerting you that you have to reupload that js file... Try my own plugin

http://jsfiddle.net/TPQyY/6/

works fine

```
(function($){
        $.fn.scrollTo = function(minus){
                if (!minus) minus = 0;
                var container = $("body");
                var scrollTo = $(this);
                if (scrollTo && container){
                        container.animate({
                            scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top - minus
                        });
                }
        }
})(jQuery);


$(function() {

     $('.next').click(function(e) {
         $('ul#scrollThis').scrollTo();    
         return false;
     });

 });
```

Comment: yeah I noticed the alert after creating the fiddle, but on my local copy I am not hotlinking and it still doesn't work. I would use your custom plugin but I am working on a project that already uses this one in many places so I need to use the scrollTo plugin and it also needs to scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the creator of jQuery.scrollTo.
I think 2 people already answered correctly (it's a CSS thing) so I won't repeat it.

I just wanted to add that in order to use a modern version, ensure availability and consistency you can either:

- download it from https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo/releases and host it yourself
- Hotlink to one of the free CDN services hosting the plugin

  - https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-scrollto
  - http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!jquery.scrollto (not the latest)